# asp.net ShieldUI bar chart dates

Tags: javascript, asp.net, shieldui

I’m currently trying to implement a ShieldUI bar chart with dates as the X axis as defined by a date group in my data and I’m finding that the graph is shifting the data by one month. So, data that is supposed to be for 1/2017 is being graphed as 12/2016.

The ShieldUI suite I'm using is asp.net. The data is being brought over from SQL Server using a SQLDataSource object. I know that the underlying "engine" for the ShieldUI stuff is javascript and I also know that javascript uses zero based dates. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the chart to graph the dates correctly?

Thanks in advance for the help.

--Edit: To help visualize what is happening, the data being passed to the graph from SQL Server looks like this:

Date Group Company A  Company B  Company C

1/1/2016   3          22         14        ---This row graphs out as Dec 2015

2/1/2016   3          11         18        ---This row graphs out as Jan 2016

3/1/2016   1          3          25        ---This row graphs out as Feb 2016

4/1/2016   3          14         17        ---This row graphs out as Mar 2016

5/1/2016   NULL       7          16        ---This row graphs out as Apr 2016

6/1/2016   NULL       6          10        ---This row graphs out as May 2016

7/1/2016   NULL       8          23        ---This row graphs out as Jun 2016

8/1/2016   2          12         18        ---This row graphs out as Jul 2016

9/1/2016   3          9          20        ---This row graphs out as Aug 2016

10/1/2016  2          16         17        ---This row graphs out as Sep 2016

11/1/2016  2          4          11        ---This row graphs out as Oct 2016

12/1/2016  3          9          18        ---This row graphs out as Nov 2016

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you have a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for what you are doing now? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve